# How I open in one link a circle loader 4sec and after that a new page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to click in the button NEXT and happend two things:
1) Show up a circle loader for about 4sec in the middle of screen and after that
2) Show up a new page in the same Tab.
I can't handle it. I tried with this code but of course it's not running. Maybe needs also some jquery, I don't know.

My HTML is:

```
<a href="#modalloader (for 4 sec)" href="new_page.html (in the same tab after 4sec)" class="btn">
    NEXT <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
</a>
<div id="modalloader">                                                                                        
  <div class="loader-block">
     <div class="loader"></div>
     <div class="stop">STOP</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My Css is:

```
.modalloader{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.loader-block{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -90px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

.loader {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 4px solid #2d4371;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #2d4371;
  border-right:4px solid #2d4371;
  border-left:4px solid #9A9999;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}

.stop{
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #2d4371;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 3px 2px #506184;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Any idea fellows!!??

Comment: You will need to use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it this way :

Create a `div` that will contain the circle loader and give it an ID (I'll use `circle_lodr` in this example) and set the DIV's `z-index` to a negative value in your CSS (negative values aren't accepted as `z-index` therefore it won't be displayed on the page until we change the `z-index`'s value ourself later on). Then set its `opacity`to 0 in your CSS.

Now we'll add a bit of javascript (remember that you'll also need jQuery for this) :

```
$(/*insert jQ selector for the button that activates the thingie*/).click(function(){
  var $loader = $("#circle_lodr"/*your DIV*/);
  $loader.css("zIndex",999);/*any value that would put it on top*/
  /*trigger the circular loading animation here*/
  $loader.animate({
    opacity: 1
  },{
    duration:/*some duration in ms, I recommend 500*/,
    queue:false;/*usual settings ;)*/
  });

  setTimeout(function(){
    document.location.href="";/*replace this empty string with a string containing the url*/
  }, 4000);/*4000ms <=> 4s, will wait 4s before switching to the page, I used the document.location.href because you wanted to stay on the same page, if not read about window.open()*/
});
```

You need to put this bit of JS in a  `$(document).ready();` just like this (just replace `/*the func*/` with the JS code that is above) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  /*the func*/
});
```

And there you have it.